# Вызов хранимой процедуры через sp_executesql необъяснимо работает

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Есть существующая БД с большим кочичеством sp.

Заглоловок - такой:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[fileGet]
    @fileId INT = NULL
    ,@parentId INT = NULL
    ,@getContent INT = NULL
    ,@showDeleted INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON;
....
```

Нужно написать API на  Net Core к существующей БД. И вот тут то начались проблемы с вызовом.
Параметры принимают по умолчанию NULL и могут быть опущены. При вызове из студии

```
exec fileGet @parentId=7
exec fileGet @fileId=NULL, @parentId=7
```

результаты будут одинаковы.

Но при обращении из ef.core вызовы процедуры оборачиваются в вызов SQL через sp_executesql. И эти же запросы в Profiler уже выглядят так:

```
exec sp_executesql N'fileGet @parentId',N'@parentId int',@parentId=7
exec sp_executesql N'fileGet @fileId, @parentId', N'@fileId int,@parentId int', @fileId=NULL, @parentId=7
```

И результаты запросов - разные. Второй запрос вернет те же данные, что и прямой вызов "exec fileGet", а вот второй
будет отрабатывать так же как exec fileGet @fileId=7 и пофигу ему на именованные параметры.

Перечислять при вызовах все параметры в нужном порядке очень бы не хотелось, в некоторых sp таких параметров до 40 и писать 38 раз присваивание NULL очень не хотелось бы. Какой можно найти выход?

= Дополнение.
Код на стороне приложения:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

//......

SqlParameter _empty = new("@fileId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
            _empty.Value = DBNull.Value;

SqlParameter _param = new("@parentId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
_param.Value = request.UserId;



List<ObjFile> alternate = await ctx.ObjFiles
       .FromSqlRaw("fileGet @fileId, @parentId", _empty, _param)
       .AsNoTracking()
       .ToListAsync();
// alternate.Count = 1


List<ObjFile> emptyAlternate = await ctx.ObjFiles                
       .FromSqlRaw("fileGet @parentId", _param)
       .AsNoTracking()
       .ToListAsync();
// emptyAlternate.Count = 0
```

Comment: Вот так: `fileGet @parentId` - это не именованные параметры, это передаётся значение переменной `@parentId` в первый параметр процедуры (т.е. в `@fileId`). То же самое как если бы в студии сделали `declare @parentId int = 7; exec fileGet @parentId;`. А должно быть так: `fileGet @parentId = @parentId` - передаём значение переменной `@parentId` в параметр `@parentId`.

Comment: Покажите код, как вызываете их в EF.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov - Добавил код в вопрос

Comment: @i-one - Вы совершенно правы, работает